# Is there an algebraic homomorphism between two Banach algebras which is not continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, set-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#Axiom_of_choice), you need the Axiom of Choice to find a discontinuous map between two Banach spaces.

Does this procedure also apply for Banach algebras yielding a discontinuous multiplicative linear map?

Or, is there some obstruction, ensuring that every algebraic homomorphism between two Banach algebras is continuous? (I know that this is true for $*$-homomorphisms between C*-algebras.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"There are" examples of discontinuous homomorphisms between Banach algebras. However, the quotes are there because the question is *independent* of the usual axioms of set theory. I quote from the introduction to W. Hugh Woodin, "[A discontinuous homomorphism from $C(X)$ without CH](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-48.2.299)", J. London Math. Soc. (2) 48 (1993), no. 2, 299-315, [MR1231717](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1231717):

> Suppose that $X$ is an infinite compact Hausdorff space and let $C(X)$ be the algebra of continuous real-valued functions on $X$. Then $C(X)$ is a commutative Banach algebra relative to the supnorm: ${}\|f\|= \sup\{f(p)\mid p\in X\}$. A well-known question of I. Kaplansky posed around 1947 asks whether every algebra homomorphism of $C(X)$ into a Banach algebra $B$ is necessarily continuous.
>
> There is a discontinuous homomorphism of $C(X)$ if and only if there is a discontinuous homomorphism of $C(X, {\mathbb C})$, the $C^*$-algebra of continuous complex-valued functions on $X$. We prefer to deal with the real case; some of the references adopt the complex view. The question is now known to be independent of the axioms of set theory, ZFC. H. G. Dales [[1]](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2373803) and J. Esterle [[3]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-36.1.59) independently constructed discontinuous homomorphisms of $C(X)$ for any infinite space $X$ assuming the 
>   Continuum Hypothesis, CH. About the same time R. Solovay [4] proved that it is relatively consistent with ZFC that every homomorphism of $C(X)$ for any space X is necessarily continuous. Solovay's result was improved [5] fairly soon thereafter, to obtain the relative consistency with ZFC + [Martin's Axiom](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2373803) (ZFC + MA) that every homomorphism of $C(X)$ for any space $X$ is continuous. We refer the reader to [[2]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511662256) for an exposition of the latter result concerning MA, historical points and related results.
>
> After these results several questions remained. This paper is concerned with the question of whether the existence of a discontinuous homomorphism of $C(X)$ is possible given the failure of the Continuum Hypothesis.

The references listed above are:

1. H. G. Dales, "[A discontinuous homomorphism from $C(X)$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2373803)" Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) 647-734. [MR533196](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=533196)
2. H. G. Dales and H. Woodin, [An introduction to independence for analysts](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511662256), London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes 115 (University Press, Cambridge, 1987). [MR942216](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=942216) and [Review by M. Alain Louveau](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183555150) in the Bulletin of the AMS
3. J. R. Esterle, "[Injection de semi-groupes divisibles dans des algebres de convolution et construction d'homomorphismes discontinus de $C(K)$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-36.1.59)" Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 36 (1978) 59-85. [MR482218](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=482218)
4. R. Solovay, personal communication, unpublished.
5. H. Woodin, Set theory and discontinuous homomorphisms from Banach algebras, Ph.D. Thesis, University of California at Berkeley, 1984.

I believe Solovay's original construction is simply superseded by Hugh's result, as described in his thesis. In any case, reference 2 is particularly good to learn about this fascinating topic.

Shortly after, in Stevo Todorcevic, [Partition Problems in Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=k6UZnZ_qkgIC) (Contemporary Mathematics), American Mathematical Society (January 1989), [MR980949](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=980949), it is shown that automatic continuity of homomorphisms between Banach algebras is a theorem of ZFC + PFA. PFA is the [proper forcing axiom](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511662256), a strengthening of Martin's axiom.

There is also a much more recent reference: H. Garth Dales, Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity (London Mathematical Society Monographs New Series), Oxford University Press, USA (May 17, 2001). [MR1816726](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1816726) and [Review by George Willis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0024609302221256) in the Bulletin of the LMS.

**Added:** (T.B.) An excellent first introduction to automatic continuity is H.G. Dales's contribution (Part I) to Dales et. al. [Introduction to Banach algebras, operators, and harmonic analysis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511615429), LMS Student Texts, Cambridge University Press (2003) electronic version (2009), [MR2060440](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2060440)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding links to the papers, MathSciNet reviews and a further reference which I find excellent for a beginner.

Answer (score 9):

You can construct a "silly" example of a discontinuous homomorphism as follows: Let $\omega: E \to \mathbb{C}$ be any discontinuous linear functional on a Banach space.  (Assuming the Axiom of Choice, this exists.)  Turn both $E$ and $\mathbb{C}$ into Banach algebras $E_0$ and $\mathbb{C}_0$ by defining the product of any two elements to be zero.  N. B. that this is *not* the standard Banach algebra structure on $\mathbb{C}$, of course.  The map $\omega$ is then a discontinuous homomorphism from $E_0$ to $\mathbb{C}_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a Banach space and denote by $B(X)$ the Banach algebra of all bounded linear operators on $X$. It is well-known that if $X$ is isomorphic to $X\oplus X$, then any homomorphism from $B(X)$ into any Banach algebra is continous. Charles Read constructed however an example of a space $X_R$ such that $B(X_R)$ admits a discontinuous homomorphism.

> C. J. Read, Discontinuous derivations on the algebra of bounded operators
>   on a Banach space, *J. London Math. Soc.* **40** (1989), 305–326.

A recent PhD thesis by Skillicorn contains a synthesis of the subject (in particular Lemma 1.3.3 therein gives you description of such homomorphism).

> R. Skillicorn, [*Discontinuous Homomorphisms from
>   Banach Algebras of Operators*](http://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/79356/1/2016skillicornphd.pdf), PhD thesis, Lancaster 2016.

You may also like the paper

> R. Skillicorn, [The uniqueness-of-norm problem for Calkin algebras](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.3318/pria.2015.115.14?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents),
>   *Math. Proc. R. Ir. Acad.* **115** A (2015), 145–152.

which describes an example of discontinuous homomorphism on $B(X) / K(X)$, the Calkin algebra of $X$.